# jQuery.on() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change some things in my wordpress lightbox plugin when click event is fired on it. The lightbox itself is injected after the page is loaded so I have to use `on()`.

Javascript in the header:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("body").on("click", "#lightbox img", function() { 
        alert("t");
    });
});
```

I never see an `alert`. I tried changing the `#lightbox img` selector to `div` and still nothing.

EDIT: i get no error on chrome console and fixed the syntax error, which was caused by removing the functions that were useless for the question.

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in the console?

Comment: The code you posted is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`.

Comment: Once fixed for the syntax, this code seems correct. Your error doesn't seem to be visible to us.

Comment: OP, you've edited to remove one parenthesis but you should also change `(function)` to `function()`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Syntax Error

```
jQuery(document).ready((function){
----------------------^---------^
jQuery("body").on("click","#lightbox img",(function(){alert("t");});
------------------------------------------^
```

1. Move the first brace after the second brace!
2. Why is there a open brace? Remove it!

#### Let me post the right code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("body").on("click", "#lightbox img", function() {
        alert("t");
    });
});
```

Comment: That's the game : find the other syntax errors :)

Comment: Messed it up when editing the code. Im sorry, i get no syntax error in the chrome console.

Comment: Okay @SuperKingTurban, remove those two braces and try again! :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar still doesn't. I see another one.

Comment: In fact the other one should be moved, not removed.

Comment: @dystroy Updated! :) Thakns.

Comment: `Thakns` : syntax error :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct your syntax. You have 2 braces that don't have to be there

```
jQuery(document).ready((function){
 ----------------------^
"#lightbox img", (function() { 
 ----------------^
```

It should be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("body").on("click", "#lightbox img", function() {
        alert("t");
    });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. What about the closing paren after `function`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Holy moly! That's a lot of misplaced braces :)